# How can I know the dates of the files uploaded in azure file share

Tags: python, azure

I have a file share in azure, and I want to list the content of the files, as well the date of the upload, so that I can see the most recent files uploaded.
I managed to list the files, however I can not see the dates of the upload. Here is my code:

```
from azure.storage.file import FileService

file_service = FileService(account_name='', account_key='')
generator = list(file_service.list_directories_and_files(''))


try:
    for file_or_dir in generator:
        properties= file_service.get_file_properties(share_name='', directory_name="", file_name=file_or_dir.name)

        print(file_or_dir.name, file_or_dir.properties.__dict__)

except ResourceNotFoundError as ex:
    print('ResourceNotFoundError:', ex.message)
```

When I use the __dict__properties, I got this result:

file_name.zip {'last_modified': None, ...}

UPDATE

with this code, it works:

```
from azure.storage.file import FileService


file_service = FileService(account_name='', account_key='')
generator = list(file_service.list_directories_and_files(''))


try:
    for file_or_dir in generator:
        file_in = file_service.get_file_properties(share_name='', directory_name="", file_name=file_or_dir.name)
        print(file_or_dir.name, file_in.properties.last_modified)

except ResourceNotFoundError as ex:
    print('ResourceNotFoundError:', ex.message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When you list files and directories in an Azure File Share, very minimal information is returned. For files, only the file name and size is returned.

To get other properties of a file, you will need to separately call [`get_file_properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.fileservice.FileService?view=azure-python#get-file-properties-share-name--directory-name--file-name--timeout-none--snapshot-none-) for each file in the list. The result of this operation will contain the last modified date of the file.

**Update**

Please try something like (untested code):

```
try:
    for file_or_dir in generator:
        properties = file_service.get_file_properties(share_name="share-name", directory_name="", file_name=file_or_dir.name)
        print(file_or_dir.name, properties.__dict__)
```

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, whenever I try to use get_file_properties like this: file_properties = file_service.get_file_properties('name'), I get an error, to specify directory_name, file_name... But since I am working with azure file share, I don't have a directory exactly.

Comment: Please specify an empty string for the directory name if the files are present in the root of file share.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.

Comment: hi @Gaurav, sorry but it continues to give error...

Comment: Are you getting the same error?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238395/discussion-between-sofia-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: I updated my answer, with the code that works now. Thanks for your help. I updated your code with different variables.